# How to pad list with periods in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles, tables, formatting

I've got a text block in InDesign, it's a list, and I'd like to pad the list with periods (to the right of the list elements), so that the padding terminates at the right edge of the text box. How can this be done in InDesign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Insert a TAB character after each list element
- Select all your list elements and open up the Tabs window as seen below (CTRL+SHIFT+T)
- Insert a tab marker at the end of the line, make it right aligned and put a '.' in the 'Leader' field

Is this what you needed?

[image]

Comment: you can use "any" combination of up to 8 (?) characters for the leader BTW, including glyphs (place the glyph, then copy'n'paste to the dialog)

Comment: You can also use a space as a character. I usually do <space><period><space> so the periods are not so close together.